# Как превратить input в span с текстом javascript(no jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как превратить input в span с текстом javascript без jquery?

Код замены с jquery

```js
$('.simpleCart_input').replaceWith(function(){
   return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1" class="simpleCart_input"/>
```

Comment: Вообще то ни как...  Ты можешь удалить один элемент, а потом другой вставит... А какой то элемент превратить в другой ни как...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $input = document.querySelector(".simpleCart_input");
var $span = document.createElement("span");

$span.innerHTML = $input.value;

$input.parentNode.replaceChild($span, $input);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1" class="simpleCart_input"/>
```

Comment: Kirill Korushkin, привет, твой первый изучаемый  язык php? ))))

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Air, в жиквери нынче тоже принято переменные с $ начинать, так что не факт ... xDD

Comment: @Air в общем-то да... Я так очень хочу думать =)

Comment: @MedvedevDev, Для меня нет разницы с чего начинать...  Это вопрос-шутка... )))

Comment: @Air ааа )) Это привычка как-раз от jQuery - переменной селектора добавлять алиас =)